# How to Extract Data From a String Into Two Arrays

Tags: c#, string, extract

I have string which contains two sets of data, call it 1 and 2 respectively. In the data strings each are separated by symbol `@` or `&` like:

> @data1&data2@data1&data2@....

I want to extract it to become an array such as `x[] = all the data1`, `y[] = data2`

I tried the method `strtok` but after processing of the string the method gave me an inverted string like this:

"abcd" becomes an array of 
    `d`
    `c`
    `b`
    `a`

Which does not work for my situation because I need to split it into two arrays in the order in which it was found.

Comment: you should post your code as well as your example should reflect the string that you showed, @data1&data2@data1&data2@ does not equal your example abcd --> d c b a.  Hard to tell what it is you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: You should post the code you have written to help us answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what exactly is stored in your `data1`, `data2`, etc, but it seems like you need to use `Split()` method of your string.

```
string input = "@data1&data2@data1&data2@";
string[] splitInput = input.Split({'@', '&'});
```

Each element of `splitInput` will contain one of your data blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data format is **unchanged**

```
string input = "@data1&data2@data3&data4";

var keyValues = input.Split(new[] { '@'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) // split to ["data1&data2", "data3&data4"]
                .Select(i => i.Split('&')) // split to [ ["data1", "data2"], ["data3" , "data4"] ]
                .Select(k => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k[0], k[1]));

var x = keyValues.Select(s => s.Key); // x array
var y = keyValues.Select(s => s.Value); // y array
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions allow one to parse and extract based on patterns within the "reg-ex" language.

---

For example to create a pattern follow these steps.

1. One knows that there is a literal character `@` and a literal character `&`. So an initial pattern contains `@ &`.
2. Then we need to **match and capture** the text after those items to put into X and Y. That is done in regular expression by specifying a match capture set of `( )`. So now our pattern looks like this `@()&()`.
3. To match *any text* one can say `\w+`. Which says we are looking for a word type character (a-Z and 0-9) which can be represented as a `\w`. Since we are looking for 1 or more characters, we add a `+` to the `\w` making it `\w+`. Now our pattern looks like this `@(\w+)&(\w+)`
4. With the pattern we expect two sets of data to be returned from the regex parser which will return two `Match` instances.
5. Now we extract the data from the match sets.
6. With the two sets of data, an X and Y, we will create individual arrays.

---

```
string data = "@data1&something1@data2&something2";

string pattern = @"@(\w+)&(\w+)"; 
// The C# literal character `@` must precede the string holding regex pattern.

var matches = Regex.Matches(data, pattern)
                   .OfType<Match>()
                   .Select(mt => new { X = mt.Groups[1].Value, Y = mt.Groups[2].Value })
                   .ToList();

// See what the data looks like in `matches`

var XArray = matches.Select(item => item.X).ToList(); 

// See what the data looks like in "XArray"

var YArray = matches.Select(item => item.Y).ToList();

// See what the data looks like in "YArray"
```

[image]

---

**To Learn More See**

- [Introduction to Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28hw3sce(v=vs.100).aspx)
- Look at [.NET Framework Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.100).aspx)

Even though the documentation is for Visual Studio 2010, it still is ok and good to use.

Comment: sorry I'm try to understand what u say, but I false. Can u make it easy . Thank u a lot

Comment: @PhamCongTheAnh  Tìm hiểu các biểu thức thông thường. Sau đó đọc tác phẩm của tôi một lần nữa. (Learn regular expressions. Then read my writings again.)